# Strapi Admin console page working and trying to load indefinitely

Tags: gatsby, strapi

My Admin page on Strapi is not working. My server.js file has:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
   host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
   port: env.int('PORT', 80),
   admin: {
     port: 3000
   }
});
```

However, when I run my admin page `http://localhost/admin`, I'm seeing it making a GET request against `http://internal-test.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/users-permissions/init` which doesn't make any sense because, from my `server.js` it has `0.0.0.0` as the *host* so I'm thinking the GET request should go against `http://localhost/users-permissions/init` which is not the case. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Within the Strapi project, there's a path `./app/.cache`, Delete it, rebuild and start your project and it'll work. The issue is that my admin URL (which is based on my server URL and not localhost) was cached there.